# Angular 2 RC1: DataBinding and ComponentResolver

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I've recently updated my project from beta.15 to RC1. Now, `DynamicComponentLoader` is deprecated. So I've re-writed my code using `ComponentResolver`.

My component is correctly loaded into another but I'm experiencing an issue : data-binding seems to doesn't works.

Here is my code :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'browser-pane',
    styleUrls: ['src/modules/component@browser/src/styles/pane.css'],
    template: `
        <li class="pane">
            <ul class="nodes">
                <li *ngFor="let node of nodes; let i = index" id="node-{{i}}"></li>                        
            </ul>
        </li>
    `
})
export class PaneComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() nodeId: number;
    @Input() nodes: any[];
    @Input() fillerComponent: any;
    @Input() mapComponentData: any;

    constructor(private _injector: Injector, private _cr: ComponentResolver) {}

    ngOnInit(): any {
        this.nodes.forEach((node: any, i: number) => {
            this._cr.resolveComponent(this.fillerComponent)
                .then((factory: ComponentFactory) => factory.create(this._injector, null, `#node-${i}`))
                .then((ref: ComponentRef<any>) => this.mapComponentData(ref.instance, node));
        })
    }
}
```

`mapComponentData` is just a function which map data to the component ref. In my case, the component that I'm creating dynamically needs an `@Input()` named 'media'. This function will do the following instruction: `myComponentInstance.media = media;`.

Here is the filler component (simplified) :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'cmp-media-box',
    styleUrls: ['src/modules/component@media-node/src/style.css'],
    pipes: [ MediaCountPipe ],
    template: `
        <div class="media-node" 
        (click)="onClick()"
        (dragover)="onDragover($event)" 
        (drop)="onDrop($event)" 
        [class.dropDisable]="!drop">
            <span class="title">{{ media.title }}</span>
            <div class="box" [class.empty]="isEmpty()">{{ media | mediaCount:'playlists':'channels' }}</div>
        </div>
    `
})
export class MediaNodeComponent {
    @Input() media: Media;
    private _OSelection:Observable<Media[]>;
    private _selectionSubscription: Subscription;
    private _removeAllFromSelection;
    drop: boolean = false;

    constructor(private _store:Store<AppStore>, private _mediaService:MediaService) {
        setTimeout(() => this.initialize(), 0);
    }

    initialize():any {
        if(this.media.type === MEDIA) {
            this._OSelection = this._store.select(s => s['data@media'].selected);
            this._removeAllFromSelection = mediaRemoveAll;
        } else if(this.media.type === CHANNEL) {
            this._OSelection = this._store.select(s => s['data@channel'].selected);
            this._removeAllFromSelection = channelRemoveAll;
        }
        this.subscribeToSelection();
    }
    // ...
}
```

So what's the problem ? Inside this`fillerComponent`, `this.media` is defined. If i put a `console.log(this.media)` inside `initialize`, I can see it. But I can't use it inside the template. I've tried many things :

- use `{{media?.title}}`
- use `{{media.title | async}}`
- remove the `@Input()` in front of the media declaration
- stop passing `media` and use a hard-coded variable (just in case)
- use `DynamicComponentLoader` : same result. But I think that dcl uses `ComponentResolver` behind (not sure about that, I'm checking this point)
- ...

In other words : I can't use variables inside my template.

What am I doing wrong ?

Speaking about this code, there is another thing that I don't understand. I can't use `OnInit` on the filler component: `ngOnInit()` will never be triggered. That's why I'm using this horrible `setTimeout()`.

Comment: What is `fillerComponent` how is this related to `ComponentFactory`. Can you create a Plunker.

Comment: Okay so I've found a workaround on [Github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6223#issuecomment-171114590). I use `setTimeout(() => this._changeDetector.detectChanges(), 0);` after the other `setTimeout()`. This is not a solution so every idea i a good thing :)

Comment: `fillerComponent` is a component definition passed as a variable (this is allow some custom configurations).

Comment: That doesn't really help. Please create a Plunker that allows to reproduce and investigate.

Comment: [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ajsO0gize33BEib2xb5w?p=preview) is a plunker. Here the ngOnInit should run when click the button if it is binded. And if I understand he/she want to bind inputs.